# S3 programmatic access via Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'd need to create out of my Java program a private S3 bucket and  an IAM user that is allowed to access that bucket only.

So I'd have some admin account credentials to create an S3Client

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
  .standard()
  .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
  .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
  .build();
```

and then with some null checks and so on create my bucket

```
s3client.createBucket(bucketName);
```

Now I'd need to block all public access to this bucket (Can I?)

And create an IAM user with AWS Credential Type equal "Access key - Programmatic access" and set its policy to something like this, so that it can only access that bucket I just created ([Just a snippet from the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket.html))

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Yes, all that is possible, those just require a lot of API calls. You need to go through the S3 and IAM api and look for the right calls, e.g. for CreateUser, CreateAccessKey, CreatePolicy, AttachUserPolicy, ....

Comment: You don't need to block public access to a newly-created S3 bucket. In the absence of a policy that explicitly allows public access, the bucket is private. Also note that there is an overarching bucket and/or account-level setting called [Block Public Access](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/block-public-access/) that you should be aware of, and use if it suits your purpose either at the bucket level or at the account level (to prevent users mistakenly making a bucket or object public).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I did find a pretty good solution.
[Sampler](https://github.com/hons82/vaadin_sampler/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/application/services/AwsS3Service.java)

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is a main question to have a security in the bucket level or in the IAM level.

In the approch **"What can this user do in AWS?"** you can explore using IAM Policy ( managed policy, inline policy...)

In the approch **Who can access this S3 bucket?** then you can explore using S3 Bucket policy to centralize security in the bucket to accounts...

By default any new bucket is in a mode no public accessible, and any user IAM have permissions to S3 **can** access it.